# How to rewrite URLs using htaccess only for images

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

This is the current URL of my images -

```
http://www.mysite.com/files/thumb/133/595
```

While inspecting it in firebug, this is the code under image tag -

```
<img src="http://www.mysite.com/files/thumb/133/595" alt="This is text">
```

Now i want the above URLs to be changed like this -

```
http://www.mysite.com/files/thumb/133/595/This-is-text.jpg
```

Image extension(`.jpg` in this case) added automatically on the type of image and alt text is added to the link with space being replaced from `-`.

How can i achieve this? via `htaccess` or some other method( project is in `php`).

How to rewrite my htaccess file that this change will only take place for images only.(Newbie in re-writing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this in htaccess, because the **This is text"** alternate text is never sent to the server and is only part of the HTML mark up. You need to change your site so that instead of:

```
<img src="http://www.mysite.com/files/thumb/133/595" alt="This is text">
```

At every place throughout your entire site, they'd look like this:

```
<img src="http://www.mysite.com/files/thumb/133/595/This-is-text.jpg" alt="This is text">
```

Not sure how your site is built, whether this is a one-line-change in some script or whether this involves a search and replace for every file. Once you have that, if you want to use mod_rewrite to *rewrite these URL's **back** to the original*, then you'd do something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?files/thumb/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/.+\.jpg$ /files/thumb/$1/$2 [L]
```

Essentially, ditching anything after the 2 numbers.

Comment: plz elaborate this line as i m very new to URl rewriting -- RewriteRule ^/?files/thumb/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/.+\.jpg$ /files/thumb/$1/$2 [L]

Comment: @user1594368 Look over [apache's documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule), The first parameter is a pattern, it matches against a URI, if that matches, then the next parameter is the target and the URI is rewritten to that target

Comment: Wow this is really an interesting article..i dunno about this..it would be really appreciable if u provide a link that enhance my learning over URL re-writings as google in not helping much as a starter for this topic :(

Comment: @user1594368 you can start here http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/ which has a list of topics